# Is Log4j a dead project?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, log4j, apache-commons-logging

I recently ended up in a bit of a mess on one of the projects I work on, a "mélange" of Log4j,  Slf4j and Commons-Logging due to mixing different JARs from different open source projects.

I see more and more OS projects slowly moving to Slf4j. Logback seems to be the successor of Log4j. I think it's actually a fork, but since no further development are anticipated for Log4j 1.3 and Log4j 2.0 is an experimental development and don't know if it will ever leave that state... I wonder!!!

Is Log4j dead?

Comment: No...? Why would you think that?

Comment: Log4j is a pretty comprehensive logging framework, in my experience.  Perhaps it is simply done, and not dead.  What new features were you hoping to see added to it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Log4j being abandoned in favor of Slf4j?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063883/is-log4j-being-abandoned-in-favor-of-slf4j)

Comment: "Its just resting after a long squawk".

Answer (score 10):

**No.**

Mature, complete, stable - none of these are synonyms for "dead".

Deprecated, superceded - perhaps this is what you meant?  Is Log4j superceded by Slf4j?  Given that Slf4j implements a [wrapper](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/impl/Log4jLoggerAdapter.html) for Log4j... probably not.  It's just an alternative way to use Log4j.

Log4j is robust, stable, widely accepted and in production use across the globe.

[Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) is intended to be a successor for Log4j but has not yet had equivalent exposure.  [Slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) allows you to abstract out the logging framework.

Comment: Yes, if you are asking about log4j not log4j2. check this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j)